# Cast in comparison function of 3D array

Tags: c, casting, multidimensional-array

I rencently removed a similar question (sorry if someone was answering), I have found a solution to skip warning (pedantic flag on) in this comparison function:

```
int comp(const void *pa, const void *pb)
{
    const int (*a)[2] = pa;
```

Warning:

```
warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
```

Solved using a cast:

```
const int (*a)[2] = (void * const)pa;
```

The complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int comp(const void *pa, const void *pb)
{
    const int (*a)[2] = (void * const)pa;
    const int (*b)[2] = (void * const)pb;

    return (a[0][0] + a[1][0]) - (b[0][0] + b[1][0]);
}

int main(void)
{
    int a[][2][2] = {
        {{1,2},{3,4}},
        {{3,4},{5,6}},
        {{2,3},{4,5}},
    };
    size_t i, n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", a[i][0][0] + a[i][1][0]);
    }
    qsort(a, n, sizeof(a[0]), comp);
    printf("Sorted:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", a[i][0][0] + a[i][1][0]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now it seems to work as expected without warnings, but I don't understand the cast, 
why `(void * const)pa` instead of `(const void *)pa`

Comment: A constant pointer to void (`void * const`)  is something different than a pointer to constant void (`void const *` or `const void *`).

Comment: So it is not correct?

Comment: You cheat the compiler using the cast.

Comment: That cast isn't necessary in C, so I'm not sure why you even have it at all.

Comment: Yes, I understand, is there a way to skip the warning using a suitable cast?

Comment: @WhozCraig, I know, but gcc shows a warning if I don't use the cast

Comment: Odd, because clang doesn't, and I religiously compile with pedantic warnings as errors (and a whole lot of added classes just for good measure). Did you try `const int (* const a)[2] = pa;` ?

Comment: Thank you Whoz, but `const int (* const a)[2] = pa;` shows the same warning

Comment: Ok, this is lame. Try as I might I cannot generate that warning. What gcc ver are you using?

Comment: gcc (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2

Comment: You're going to get this resolved before I get my fingers on a rig that I can play with, and for that I'm sorry because this is going to bug me until I see it.

Comment: Adding to the lameness, ideone.com uses gcc 4.8 (I believe), and [it works fine there as well, no warnings](http://ideone.com/8lfXOY)

Comment: @WhozCraig, same Warning :(, and as you say, in clang (even with Wcast-qual and Wconversion) it compiles without warnings

Comment: Exactly. you could always try something stupid, like reversing the const and type (and keeping the inner const), so `int const(* const a)[2] = pa;` or in the params, or both, but that stands no chance of working. I even checked my dbg and the type reports correctly. sometimes gcc just chaps me.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to get some sleep. In an absolute pinch you could put back the cast, but as long as you're doing that , cast it to the correct type, `int const (*a)[2] = (int const (*)[2])pa;`. I'm bookmarking this to check back on it. I have an ubuntu box at work I can play with tomorrow (today, actually), so if I get a chance I'll play with it a little more. this is just odd to me. I wish you the best of luck.

Comment: Yes, `int const (*a)[2] = (int const (*)[2])pa;` works like a charm :), thank you, and please, put this as an answer

Comment: Well, it is an answer, but not to the question *I'm* having right now, which is wtf is wrong with gcc =P. I'll be sure and throw that disclaimer in my post.

Comment: jajaja ok, thank you again Whoz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot explain why gcc isn't doing this right. `const void*` means an untyped pointer to unmodifiable data. Not to be confused with `void * const`, an unmodifiable pointer to untyped data. Your declaration *should* work.

But alas, in a pinch, do this:

```
int const (*a)[2] = (int const (*)[2])pa;
```

Likewise with the second param. Hideous, but at least it squelches your warning. if I ever find out why this is happening or some wiser soothsayer wants to chime in i'll be sure and post back here.

All the best.